# finding files in a dir

Tags: php, list, dir

I have a directory with a lot of files inside:

```
pic_1_79879879879879879.jpg
pic_1_89798798789798789.jpg
pic_1_45646545646545646.jpg
pic_2_12345678213145646.jpg
pic_3_78974565646465645.jpg
etc...
```

I need to list only the pic_1_ files. Any idea how I can do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opend dir function will help you

```
$dir ="your path here";

$filetoread ="pic_1_";
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
               if (strpos($file,$filetoread) !== false)
                echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
```

good luck see php.net opendir

Answer (score 9):

Use the [glob()](https://www.php.net/glob) function

```
foreach (glob("directory/pic_1_*") as $filename) {
  echo "$filename";
}
```

Just change `directory` in the glob call to the proper path.

This does it all in one shot versus grabbing the list of files and then filtering them.

Answer (score 4):

This is what [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) is for:

> glob — Find pathnames matching a pattern

Example:

```
foreach (glob("pic_1*.jpg") as $file)
{
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: @RDL: Yep was typing lazily and skimming through comments on php.net while you were posting - not copying, thank you for mentioning glob as others have missed, I did give you a vote - wish I could give you three - this glob however will match only .jpgs

Comment: I figured as such.  That happens to me all the time too.  I just beat you to the punch is all.  I gave you a vote up too b/c you are correct.  Agreed, I'm surprised how many people don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scandir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to list all the files in a directory and then use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to get the list of files which match the pattern you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the samples from the manual

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "$file\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

you can modify that code to test the filename to see if it starts with pic_1_
using something like this

```
if (substr($file, 0, 6) == 'pic_1_')
```

Manual reference for substr

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php