# Is this possible with PHP to list filenames?

Tags: php

Currently I have these files in a folder:

[image]

Is it possible to make list all files that start with *server_log* and display those filenames on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5959577/1532168).

```
$dir ="your path here";

$filetoread ="server_log";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
           if (strpos($file,$filetoread) !== false)
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob). The `glob()` function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the libc `glob()` function, which is similar to the rules used by common shells.

```
$listFile = glob("/path/server_log_*");
print_r($listFile);
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution, didn't know about it :)